# Dictionary key-values not updating after for-loop in R

Tags: r, dictionary, for-loop, hash

[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwG1v.png)I am writing a for-loop in R to iterate through each row of my data-frame, and have created dictionary 'key-value' variables in a hash constructor.  My code is intended to identify the presence of various strings (i.e. `grepl("pattern", data)`) in each row, and add one to the key-value count if `grepl()` returns `TRUE`.  After iterating through the for-loop though, my dictionary values still return zero, despite the absence of errors from my script.  Since the final value for H11 should have been 5, not zero, I would appreciate any feedback on the attached snapshots that may be causing this.

[image]

Comment: In order to let others help you quickly, can you provide a small example code and show the expected output? @ user13408286

Comment: @OceanSky_U, I added a snippet in the hyperlink which shows that 'H11' was detected five times with grepl().  Considering the print line generated five times, this should have also been reflected in the key-value printout in the command line.  Instead of 'H11 : 5' though, the value still reads zero.

Comment: Please do not use images for code or data.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Comment: @ user13408286 Can you add a subset of your data by pasting the output of `dput(head(data))` and the loop code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the feedback. I figured out the issue, as it was a simple reassignment step that I excluded.